# How to recognize class by property/constant name in PHP

Tags: php, oop

My code looks something like this:

```
class Setting
{
    const SETTING_RED = 1;
    const SETTING_BLUE = 2;
}

class CLASS_A
{
    const ID = Setting::SETTING_RED;

    public static function doSomething(){
        //does something
    }
}

class CLASS_B
{
    const ID = Setting::SETTING_BLUE;

    public static function doSomething(){
        //does something different
    }
}
```

My client code looks something like this:

```
$class_id = DB::getClassId();

switch($class_id){
  case Setting::SETTING_RED: 
      CLASS_A::doSomething();
         break;
  case Setting::SETTING_BLUE: 
      CLASS_B::doSomething();
         break;
}
```

I want to get rid of this switch and somehow to call **doSomething()** method in general, without specifying the exact class. I have ID loaded from DB and I need to get a class by that ID. I guess I need most likely to reorganized this code, but I'm out of idea right now. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not use actual OOP instead of all static classes? What you're doing is no different from using regular functions and global variables. Proper OOP design would probably make this a lot easier, like `$db->getClass()->doSomething()`.

Comment: I don't use any models in this case and store just IDs of the settings to DB. There are a lot of these settings and it wouldn't be good idea to create a model for each one. So I store these IDs and when I get them from DB, I need to start from there. Do you have any idea how to better refactor this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with models. OOP allows you to substitute objects for other objects and change behaviour of your program this way. Meaning, `$db->getClass()` returns an object of type `A` or `B`, both of which have a `doSomething()` method, which you can simply call without worrying about what class exactly you're calling it on. Classes could solve your problem very trivially, but only if you use them correctly. Currently you're not using classes in a useful way. I've expressed my views on this here: [How Not To Kill Your Testability Using Statics](http://kunststube.net/static/).

Comment: You talk mostly about dependency injection and that's good of course. In my case the starting point is ID that I get from DB and I need to get a class name in order to inject it as a dependency in my client code. That's exactly where I stuck. In case I have the class name I could use DI of course, but I'm missing the step before that. Anyway, I've decided to refactor the code to and use Reflection to get class names. Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your Setting class has constanstants with unique value and names matching class names you may do so:

```
function getClassNameById($id){
    $userClassesList = array_filter(get_declared_classes(), function($className){
        // leave only user defined classes excluding Settings
        return !(new ReflectionClass($className))->isInternal() || $className == 'Setting';
    });

    foreach ($userClassesList as $className){
        $reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass($className);
        if ($reflectionClass->getConstant('ID') == $id) return $className;
    }

    return null;
}
```

And then so:

```
$class_id = DB::getClassId();

$className = getClassNameById($class_id);

if (class_exists($className)){
    $className::doSomesing();
}
```

Edit: Now function assumes that lookup classes have public ID constant.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't specific enough. Class names are actually different from IDs. Reflection does seem like a good approach to me.

Comment: For this code to work class name should be name of constant, not it's value. For example, if `const CLASS_A = 1` within class then class name can be obtained with given function `getConstantNameByValue(1)`

Comment: Yes, that's quite obvious from the code. I like it because it's very elegant and small. In case I don't get better answer, I'll probably consider refactoring class names to match constants.

Comment: It may seems more obvious, but constants are all named like CLASS_NAME_ID, then you can just modify function above to strip '_ID' from constant name to obtain class name without refactoring existing class names.

Comment: It looks like I'm very good in not being specific, sorry :) The code is updated, and it looks like more like that. So far this is the best answer I got. Thanks!

Comment: This is good solution, but in my case your first solution is better match, since the list of returned classes is much smaller and it contains only classes from my Setting class. I've decided to rename all my classes to match constant names. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this directly. Use a function in Settings.

```
class Setting
{
    const CLASS_A = 1;
    const CLASS_B = 2;

    public static function getClass($id) {
        switch($id){
          case self::CLASS_A: 
              return 'CLASS_A';
              break;
          case self::CLASS_B: 
              return 'CLASS_B';
              break;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

class CLASS_A
{
    const ID = Setting::CLASS_A;

    public static function doSomething(){
        //does something
        echo "a";
    }
}

class CLASS_B
{
    const ID = Setting::CLASS_B;

    public static function doSomething(){
        //does something different
        echo "b";
    }
}


$class_id = 1;
$class = Setting::getClass($class_id);
if($class !== false) {
    echo $class::doSomething();
}
```

Comment: It's better than my idea, but I still have to update the code in two places every time I add new class.